# How to make_pair or make_tuple with one of the elements being a union?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I have a union declaration, It is simple:

```
union VariableType
{
    bool Bool;
    int64_t Int;
    double Double;
    std::string* String;
};
```

In my header file I use this union inside some complex data types like this:

```
extern std::map<std::string, std::tuple<uint8_t, VariableType, VariableType>> PredefinedVariables;
extern std::map<std::string, std::pair<uint8_t, VariableType>> UserVariables;
```

in a cpp file I try to initialize the maps with brace initialization as follows:

```
std::map<std::string, std::tuple<uint8_t, VariableType, VariableType>> PredefinedVariables
{
    {"num_threads", std::make_tuple(1, {.Int = 1}, {.Int = 1})},
    {"commands_logging", std::make_tuple(0, {.Bool = false}, {.Bool = false})}
};
```

I get the following error:

```
error: too many arguments to function ‘constexpr std::tuple<typename std::__decay_and_strip<_Elements>::__type ...> std::make_tuple(_Elements&& ...)
[with _Elements = {}]’
         {"num_threads", std::make_tuple(1, {.Int = 1}, {.Int = 1})},
```

I tried to narrow it down, so I tested initializing a map of simpler types `std::map<std::string, std::tuple<uint8_t, uint64_t, uint64_t>>` with brace initialization and it works fine. I also tried initializing just a tuple or pair of the union type and it didn't work:

```
std::pair<uint8_t, VariableType> Tmp = std::make_pair(5, {.Int = 4});

error: no matching function for call to ‘make_pair(int, <brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
         std::pair<uint8_t, VariableType> Tmp = std::make_pair(5, {.Int = 4});
```

I have also tried initializing the union on its own using the same way, no complaints!

So why is the union initialization illegal inside `std::make_pair` or `std::make_tuple` but legal elsewhere? and how do I work around this?

I'm using g++ version 6.2.0 with Ubuntu GLIBC 2.24-3ubuntu2.

Comment: `{.Int = 1}` is C syntax. It does not work in C++.

Comment: @DietrichEpp if you do not mind me asking, if it does not work in C++ how come it worked when I initialized the union variable outside tuples and pairs?

Comment: Your compiler allows it as an extension. However, it is not valid C++.

Comment: I think this exact question came up a few days ago. Just give your union constructors and be done

Comment: @PasserBy I've tried that, it works. Can you please post this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the comment of of @PasserBy. I just added union constructors and used them to assign values instead of the brace initialization.

Worked like a charm.